# Merge [android-broadcast] and [broadcastreceiver] into [android-broadcastreceiver]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The tags [broadcastreceiver](/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver) and [android-broadcast](/questions/tagged/android-broadcast) both refer to the same thing and should be merged into [android-broadcastreceiver](/questions/tagged/android-broadcastreceiver) or [android-broadcast](/questions/tagged/android-broadcast).

Comment: This is my first post on Meta. If I've used the wrong tags, please do help me clean it up. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. These look like synonyms to me